# Modify Geth miner to filter which transactions include in the blocks

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, mining

Where should I start if Im trying to modify the Geth client to filter transactions by sender to include only specific transactions in the mined blocks ? What files of code should I understand to do it ?

Note: Im playing with a private PoA network if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you want to achieve it I'd suggest two possible places where to start.

- [validateTx in tx_pool.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/tx_pool.go#L519): This is evaluated before queuing the transaction into the pending pool, it will not affect transactions in mined blocks.
- [ApplyTransaction in state_processor](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/state_processor.go#L88): It is used to validate transactions in a block, if you fail the transaction the whole block will be discarded.